# Return Order of Magic Methods

Tags: python

I've been programming for a couple of months now and now I actually have a  question... So, if I am not completely wrong, there is just one return per call, right? Doesn't matter if its None or a certain return but there cant be like 2 return statements in one call? So lets move on to the magic methods. In which order do they get processed?

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.first} {self.second}"
def __repr__(self):
    return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.second)
```

Always the last one? Or are there differences between certain magic methods in terms of ranking systems? Or do they even get both processed but just one becomes returned=?

Comment: There can be many returns in a function (think if statements) the first one reached however is the one used

Comment: There's no "order" involved, only which method gets called in a particular context.

Comment: Yeah, but normally a retun statement just skips the current function, so in this case just running out of the current def but not out of the classs, so the other defs should still be processed, right?

Comment: `str(x)` is equivalent to `x.__str__()`,`repr(x)` is equivalent to `x.__repr__()`, etc.

Comment: i thought they would be called atomaticly if you call the class=?

Comment: Can you provide an example in which you expect a "*choice*" between those two `return` to be made?

Comment: A class isn't something you enter, its something that essentially holds the functions you're calling (in a very simple explanation)

Comment: But i am able to make something like x = class()... print(x), so i can call a class, cant i=?

Comment: Then `repr` is called, not `str`, and it has nothing to do with the `return`

Comment: why? because its the last one?

Comment: You might be getting confused about what `str(x)` means if the type of `x` doesn't define `__str__`; it simply inherits a method from a parent class. Ultimately, it might resolve to `object.__str__(x)`, which tries to call `repr` on the argument. If no more specific `__repr__` definition is found, `object.__repr__` is used.

Comment: No because the context calls `repr`

Comment: Nah, wich magic method is called doesnt matter- this was just a example-, I am just interested in wich magic method (not matter in wich case) would be processed

Comment: Again, it depends on context. `list.__str__`, for example, constructs a string using the `__repr__` method of each element of the list.

Comment: In wich world does the computer now the context?? I want to know on what it depends  I am calling a class, not a certain function not, anything just a class, i want to know in wich order the magic methods become executed

Comment: In short, you mix different things, you should read again on class methods. There is no order, no method will be executed by default. If at some point you run `print(your_object)` or `str(your_object)`, those methods will be called, respectively. There is no order to decide.

Comment: huh? isnt that the whole point of magic functions? For example the __init__ method???

Comment: Well `init` is a special case. Those you cited won't

Comment: So last question, if I print this (so the class) why do I get the __str__ method as a output??

Comment: def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first} adfe{self.second}"  Output: Ok adfedoki

Comment: `print` implicitly calls `str` on each of its positional arguments. `print(3)` is roughly equivalent to `sys.stdout.write(str(3) + "\n")`.

Comment: "and now I actually have a question" It seems like you have several questions, none of which is really suitable here. My advice is to try an actual **discussion forum**, such as Reddit or Quora, instead. That said, I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "in terms of ranking systems". The terminology you are using doesn't make sense: magic methods are not "processed" in any meaningful way, nor do they "become returned".

Comment: "But i am able to make something like x = class()... print(x), so i can call a class, cant i=?" The `x = MyClass()` part calls the class. The `print(x)` part does not. It calls `__str__` implicitly. It does not call `__repr__` implicitly, so there is no "ranking" or "ordering" involved. It calls `__str__` **because the internal logic of `print` says to do so**, and not for any other reason. At the interpreter prompt, `x` displays the result of `__repr__`. To do so, **the interpreter** calls `repr`, which calls the `__repr__` method. It does not call `__str__`. There is still no "ranking".

Comment: Just to point out that the order in which these methods are defined plays no role whatsoever. Whether your code contains `def __str(self)__: ...; def __repr__(self): ...;` or `def __repr(self)__: ...; def __str__(self): ...;` makes no difference. Only one method will be called in the appropriate situation, as needed. (I.e. it does not matter whether `__str__` or `__repr__` is defined first or last.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no return order. Each magic method is a hook called by the Python implementation in order to implement specific protocols.

1. `x.__str__` defines what `str(x)` means.
2. `x.__repr__` defines what `repr(x)` means.

And that's it. Well, almost.

You also need to know when `str` or `repr` might be used aside from explicit calls. Some examples:

1. `print` calls `str` on each of its arguments to ensure that it has `str` values to write to the appropriate file.
2. The interactive interpreter calls `repr` on the value of each expression it evaluates.

In addition, `object.__str__` falls back to use `__repr__`, I *think* by invoking `x.__repr__()` directly (rather than calling `repr(x)`, which would then call `x.__repr__()`). So `str(x)` can indirectly be implemented using a `__repr__` method if no class involved defined a `__str__` method.

Other *groups* of magic methods might cooperate in order to define a more complicated protocol. For example,

```
x += y
```

could involve several options, tried in order:

1. `x = x.__iadd__(y)`, if `x.__iadd__` is defined
2. `x = x.__add__(y)`, if `x.__add__` is defined
3. `x = y.__radd__(x)`, if `x.__add__` is not defined or `x.__add__(y)` returned `NonImplemented`.

Comment: I think the key thing to emphasize is that magic methods *are hooks* that are *used* by various protocols defined by the language, as documented in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)